# Some ajax error, no syntax error

Tags: php, ajax

Please help, I don'tunderstand where is error. In log I have error 500.

**Script :**

```
   $('.image_reload').click(function(){
        $url = '<?php echo config_item('base_url')?>ajax/page_data/admin_add_new_article';
        $.ajax({
            url: $url,
            cashe: false
        }).done(function(html){
            $('.image_content').html(html);
        });
    });
```

---

**PHP :**

```
   public function page_data($type='')
   {
        if($type=='admin_add_new_article')
        {
             $this->load->model('Article_image_model','article_image');
             $data['result'] = $this->article_image->getImagesWithoutPattern();
             if(count($data['result']->result_arrau())>0)
             {
                   $this->load->view('admin_sub/new_article_images_prev',$data);
             }
        }
   }
```

---

Comment: If 500 internal error, then check the server log file. Ajax may be ok, problem is in server's code (are your returning the result as json?)

Comment: Using developer tools, look at the response of the network request.

Comment: Are you sure of the URL being created before the ajax call is valid?

Comment: Are you sure there was no error in the console ? i found one issue in your code, `cashe: false` should be `cache: false`.

Comment: Can you use PHP in your JS function? Is the JS in a `.php` file?

Comment: Is `admin_add_new_article` a directory or a file? Do you not need to add `.php` or `index.php` or something? Sounds like you are missing something.

Comment: >Is admin_add_new_article a directory or a file?
There is an function argument. I'm using php-framework CodeIgniter.